# postgresql 12 generated columns overhead

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

PostgreSQL 12 enables **generated** columns. Is there an overhead of using a generated column? If yes what is it?

Is table locked for read/write when such column is added?

Comment: See this Stack DBA question which is almost identical to this one: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166792/postgresql-generated-columns

Comment: no ,  this is a great feature

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The question mentioned by you is about "whether this generated column is supported". I'm asking about "what overhead will I get from such a column"

Comment: Yes, the table is locked when you run an ALTER TABLE statement.

Comment: Currently Postgres only supports `STORED` generated columns which means the value is physically stored in the column. Overhead is incurred if the row changes and the value has to be recalculated.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name doesn't alter command lock the table regardless?